# How create generic-extensions function in Kotlin, which parameter is specific enum?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to create generic-extension-function from Int to List, where E is some Enum with one Int parameter

Example, how I imagine it :

```
fun <E: Enum<Int>> Int.toEnumList(): List<E> =
    E.values()
     .filter { /* some logic */ }
     .toList
```

and I want a same result-syntax :

```
enum class Animal(val maxAge: Int) {
    CAT(15), BIRD(8), HAMSTER(4)
}

val filteredAnimals = 8.toEnumList()
// >> [BIRD, HAMSTER]
```

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no such thing like "enum with int parameter". Enum is like any other class: it could have one property, multiple properties or no properties at all. And none of them is considered its main or first parameter.

Because of that, we really need to define an interface for acquiring this int value your are interested in, for example:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface {
    val myInt: Int
}

enum class Animal(val maxAge: Int) : MyInterface {
    CAT(15), BIRD(8), HAMSTER(4);

    override val myInt get() = maxAge
}
```

Then we can use it in `toEnumList()` function. I don't know your filtering logic, so I just search for an item with the specific int value:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified E> Int.toEnumList(): List<E> where E : Enum<E>, E: MyInterface =
    enumValues<E>()
        .filter { it.myInt == this@toEnumList }

fun main() {
    println(8.toEnumList<Animal>()) // [BIRD]
}
```

Also, this is only my personal opinion, but I'm not sure such extension on `Int` is a good idea. It will clutter code completion feature whenever you do something with integers. And it does not really seem like a feature related to integers, but to enums.